# Why getting different number of records using same query & same ODBC connection from different applications?

Tags: oracle, odbc

We have an application that uses ODBC to interact with an Oracle database. It has been in use for many years starting with Oracle 9. We are now moving from Oracle 11g to Oracle 19c.

On Windows 10 using an ODBC connection from the Oracle 19c, we see fewer records retrieved for a query than when we use the same query and a connection from Oracle 11g.

On Windows 7, using either connection works and brings back the expected number of records.

I also tried using the same ODBC connection for Oracle 19c in Excel on Windows 10 and with the same query retrieved the correct number of records.

From our application log

```
2020-Nov-03 09:54:27.579 DEBUG - CODBCDynamic::CreatePreparedStatement: 'SELECT ****'. [query truncated for posting] 
2020-Nov-03 09:54:27.588 DEBUG - CODBCDynamic::BindArgument: index = 1, value = ****. 
2020-Nov-03 09:54:27.679 DEBUG - CODBCDynamic::ExecuteQuery: 0 records returned.
```

There should have been one record returned.

Any clues, ideas would be greatly appreciated

Some new info:
We've created simplified versions: one 32 bit app (like the original) and one 64 bit. The 64 bit version works OK bringing back all the records. The 32 bit one doesn't bring back all the records (like the original).

Also, I forgot to note above that we are using the 32 bit client.

Comment: The columns that you are using in the where clause, do they have NULL values in the database ?

Comment: WHERE clause: WHERE customer_fk = ? AND NVL(usestate,1)<>0 so customer_fk can't but usestate might.